# Use of anonymous method

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-methods

I haven't used anonymous methods. I found a code where a list is being iterated as shown in code snippet 1. Why would the code snippet 1 be preferred over 2?

```
    List<String> names = new List<String>(); 

    ... 
    //Code snippet 1
    names.ForEach(delegate(String name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    });

    //Code snippet 2
    foreach (string name in names)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
```

Comment: I have not known that snippet 1 is preferred over 2. Any proof?

Comment: I was also wondering why would anyone go for snippet 1. In fact, I found this in the code base of the project I am working on that someone else coded.

Comment: I would strongly prefer the second over the first. I'd only use something like the first if I need it. For example in parallel for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see snippet 1 used much at all. I do see a variation of it using lambda expressions.

```
names.ForEach(x=> Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `names.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there is no benefit.

You would find older programmers using method 2 in your example and newer programmers might use method 1.

Older programmers have more experience prior to anonymous methods, anonymous methods are new and not "ingrained in their soul" and they automatically program in style #2.

New programmers might use #1 because they keep thinking everything is a method call.

Comment: Consider reading [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) comparing the two approaches.